# multifield and reference to other nodes

Tags: views, entities

I would like to ask about my logic problem with site. I want to make a searchlist of distributors. Client selects manufacturer, and all distributors who are providing goods from certain manufacturer will be displayed. I have two content types: 1. Distributor, 2. Manufacturer. Im assigning x manufacturers to one distributor (multiple entity references). And the problem is here. I want to have for every distributor link to their shop where they offer the goods from selected manufacturer. How it can be done if one distributor can have x manufacters? I tried to search some module which dynamically adds text field for every nodereference which is set to multiple values, but didnt find anything. If I use multifield I cannot acces is aterwards with entity reference filter.

Just to be clear this is how it should look like. [image: multifield entity reference filter problem]

- Distributor1

  - Manufacturer-1
  - Manufacturer-x
  - Manufacturer-y
- Distributor2

  - Manufacturer-1
  - Manufacturer-x
  - Manufacturer-y
- Distributor3

  - Manufacturer-x
  - Manufacturer-y
  - Manufacturer-z
- Distributor4

  - Manufacturer-1
  - Manufacturer-x
  - Manufacturer-y
- Distributor5

  - Manufacturer-x
  - Manufacturer-y
  - Manufacturer-z
- Distributor6

  - Manufacturer-1
  - Manufacturer-x
  - Manufacturer-y

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you corretly, you need to store other field(s) together with the reference of Manufacturers, right? I think the best way is to add the (a single-value) reference field to Distributor in the Manufacturer content type along with other necessary fields. After that you can create your list with a View.

Comment: Thanks for reply you unerstood it right I think but one thing is little different. The distributor has many manufacturers assigned to him so if I make only single field it wont work.

Comment: That's why I suggest you to add the reference field to Manufaturer instead of Distributor. I guess one manufacturer has only one distributor.

Comment: But if you want to refering in Distributor, you can use the Field Collection modul. With it you can define a multivalue field with more fields in it.

Comment: One manifacturer is assigned also to more distributors. I tried to use field collection. The problem is to somehow connect each reference field to some manufacturer with text field where will be distributors website pointing strat to manufacurer products